# What is Stef doing in the opening credits of Goonies?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-goonies

So anyone familiar with the opening credits of [Goonies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089218/) will remember that it introduces all the characters by showing them as they are going about their daily activities, meanwhile the Fratelli's are being chased by the police in the background.

The whole scene can be seen here, however I've set the link to start at the 3 minute mark where we see the character Stef who appears to be on the docks, with her head in a giant trough(?) under water, and she comes up with a crab which she then tosses aside.  **So my question is WTF? What the heck is she doing? I mean I see what she is doing literally but... what the heck? Why is she doing that?**

[image]

Comment: God knows when I was kid I thought she was washing her hair, now I think  she was either holding her breath as some kind of competition thing or maybe she was fishing for the crab? Lets hope Hollywood never remakes this classic

Comment: The [script](https://sfy.ru/?script=goonies) sheds no further light other than she's helping her dad on the docks: `Stefanie Steinbrenner, known to her friends as Stef, is helping her
dad at the docks. The chase passes behind her while her head is
immersed in a fishing barrel. She surfaces with a crab in hand and
tosses it aside, oblivious to the commotion.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The script's [4th draft](http://goonies1632.free.fr/goon.pdf) explains that Stef is helping her father (who works at the docks) *to sort out crabs*:

> EXT. MARINA - DAY
>
> The cars are headed for a MARINA. Several FISHING BOATS are docked here. STEF, a 16 year old girl, WORKS with her father on a small FISHING BOAT. Seconds before the CHASE passes, **Stef, wearing a mask and snorkel, ducks her head into a tank of water, sorting lobsters and crabs.** As the chase PASSES out of sight, Stef RESURFACES. She MISSED all of it.

And it seems they eventually ditched the mask and snorkel in the film, probably to illustrate how tough and fearless Stef is. [Another version](https://sfy.ru/?script=goonies) of the script also states that she's helping her dad in that scene.

Comment: This seems plausible and fits the description +1

Comment: I always thought it was thievery. Nice find.